# Alternate of using NVL with IN clause in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a workplace problem to which I am looking for an easy solution. 
I am trying to replicate it in a smaller scenario.

**Problem in short**

I want to use `nvl` inside an `in` clause. Currently I have an input string which consists of a name. It is used in a where clause like below

```
and column_n = nvl(in_parameter,column_n)
```

Now I want to pass multiple comma separated values in same input parameter. So if I replace `=` with `in`, and transpose the input comma separated string as rows, I cannot use the `nvl` clause with it.

**Problem in Detail**

Lets consider an Employee table emp1.

```
Emp1
+-------+-------+
| empno | ename |
+-------+-------+
|  7839 | KING  |
|  7698 | BLAKE |
|  7782 | CLARK |
+-------+-------+
```

Now this is a simple version of an existing stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure emp_poc(in_names IN varchar2)
as
 cnt integer;
begin
 select count(*) 
  into cnt 
 from emp1 
 where 
 ename = nvl(in_names,ename); --This is one of the condition where we will make the change.
dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
```

So this will give the count of number of employees passed as Input Parameter. But if we pass null, it will return the whole count of employee becuase of the `nvl`.

So these procedure calls will render the given outputs.

```
Procedure Call          Output
exec emp_poc('KING')    1
exec emp_poc('JOHN')    0
exec emp_poc(null)      3
```

Now what I want to achieve is to add another functionality. So `exec emp_poc('KING,BLAKE')` should give me `2`. So I figured a way to split the comma separated string to rows and used that in the procedure.

So if I change the `where` clause as below to `in`

```
create or replace procedure emp_poc2(in_names IN varchar2)
as
 cnt integer;
begin
 select count(*) 
  into cnt 
 from emp1 
 where 
ename in (select trim(regexp_substr(in_names, '[^,]+', 1, level)) 
        from dual 
            connect by instr(in_names, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
          );
dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
```

So `exec emp_poc2('KING','BLAKE')` gives me `2`. But passing `null` will give result as `0`. However I want to get `3` like the case with `emp_proc` 
And I cannot use `nvl` with `in` as it expect the subquery to return a single value.

1 way I can think of is rebuilding the whole query in a variable, based in input paramteter, and then use `execute immediate`. But I am using some variables to collect the value and it would be difficult to achieve it with `execute immediate`.

I am again emphasizing that this is a simple version of a complex procedure where we are capturing many variables and it joins many tables and has multiple `AND` conditions in where clause.

Any ideas on how to make this work.

Comment: Is it mandatory the input variable (`in_names`) data type is a string or could it be a collection/container data type instead ?

Comment: It is not mandatory at all. Whatever works better, I can use that.

Comment: A comma-separated list is not a thing in SQL or PL/SQL as it is in some other languages - it's just a text string that happens to contain commas. There is no built-in way to treat it as a list of literals or an array of elements or anything else.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson can you name a language where a text string containing commas is something else than just a text string ? Or did I misread your comment ?

Comment: I had JavaScript and Bash in mind. Granted those don't exactly treat string variables containing commas as arrays, but they convert them pretty transparently in a way that SQL doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_poc2(in_names IN varchar2)
AS
 cnt integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO cnt 
    FROM emp1 
    WHERE 
        in_names IS NULL
        OR ename IN (
            SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(in_names, '[^,]+', 1, level)) 
            FROM dual 
            CONNECT BY INSTR(in_names, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
              );
    dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
END;
```

Other way could be use IF ELSE or UNION ALL

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was able to test it successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your real code is much more complex then your code readability might be greatly enhanced by using a proper collection type instead.

In the example below I have created an user defined type `str_list_t` that is a real collection of strings.

I also use common table expression (CTE) in the sql query to enhance the readability. In this simple example the CTE benefits for readability are not obvious but for all non-trivial queries it's a valuable tool.

**Test data**

```
create table emp1(empno number, empname varchar2(10));

insert into emp1 values(5437, 'GATES');
insert into emp1 values(5438, 'JOBS');
insert into emp1 values(5439, 'BEZOS');
insert into emp1 values(5440, 'MUSK');
insert into emp1 values(5441, 'CUBAN');
insert into emp1 values(5442, 'HERJAVEC');
commit;
```

**Supporting data type**

```
create or replace type str_list_t is table of varchar2(4000 byte);
/
```

**Subprogram**

```
create or replace function emp_count(p_emps in str_list_t) return number is
  v_count number;
  v_is_null_container constant number :=
    case
      when p_emps is null then 1
      else 0
    end;
begin
  -- you can also test for empty collection (that's different thing than a null collection)
  with
  -- common table expression (CTE) gives you no benefit in this simple example
  emps(empname) as (
    select * from table(p_emps)
  )
  select count(*)
    into v_count
    from emp1
   where v_is_null_container = 1
      or empname in (select empname from emps)
  ;
  return v_count;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> select 2 as expected, emp_count(str_list_t('BALLMER', 'CUBAN', 'JOBS')) as emp_count from dual
union all
select 0, emp_count(str_list_t()) from dual
union all
select 6, emp_count(null) from dual
;

  EXPECTED  EMP_COUNT
---------- ----------
         2          2
         0          0
         6          6
```

Comment: What about simply adding the enames to a table and doing a join?

Comment: @user272735 : Thanks for the reply and suggestion. I will definitely check it out and then see how it can be incorporated in the actual procedure.

Comment: @BobC I guess you're suggesting a _global temporary table_ ? Sounds a quite clever - that option has never crossed my mind ! In fact I don't recall I have ever used GTTs. I need to make a mental note about this. When I have this kind of situation the filtering list is usually a short list of id numbers (tens at max) so GTT sounds quite a bit of overkill (going to disk instead of staying in memory). However sounds an option to consider with bigger data volumes.

Comment: A GTT or even a regular heap table with a key. Chances are it would not go to disk anyway, and would be in the buffer cache.